# Reload dataTable from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I searched all over web and I didn't find easy solution for this. I'm using jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with "static" data source (one `var` is filled with data using SignalR and then later, DataTable is built). Now, when change of this dataset comes, I want to update table using this data set. Ideally, that would be simple "refresh" which reloads data from specified source. Here is my HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" id="tableAccounts">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-localize="_A_C">_A_C</th>
                <th data-localize="_Name">_Name</th>
                <th data-localize="_Address">_Address</th>
                <th data-localize="_City">_City</th>
                <th data-localize="_Phone">_Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
```

And here is my javascript which initially loads data:

```
tAccounts = $('#tableAccounts').dataTable({
            "data": AccountAll,
            "bFilter": true,
            "pageLength": 100,
            "bSearchable": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "AccountCode" },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Address" },
                { "data": "City" },
                { "data": "Phone" }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
               {
                   "render": function (data, type, row) {
                       return ("0000" + data.toString(16)).slice(-4);
                   },
                   "targets": 0
               },
               { "visible": true, "targets": [0] }
            ]
        });
```

tl;dr;

How to refresh datatable when data source (AccountAll in this case) is changed without destroying whole table? Bonus point if selection and filter is preserved.

Change can be anything. New row added, row removed, cell value changed.

Comment: Tried [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - like this? `var table = $(tableAccounts).DataTable();
            table.draw();`? No luck. Not reloading/redrawing.

Comment: @nighthawk - that code you've posted in the comment won't work as the tableAccounts selector is wrong.  Besides, you've already assigned the datatable object to `tAccounts` so you should be able to use `tAccounts.fnDraw()`. Note I've used v1.9 syntax because it looks like that's what you're using.

Answer (score 8):

You can use combination of [`clear()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) and [`rows.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) API methods to clear existing data and add updated data.

In this case filtering and sorting would be preserved.

If you want to preserver the current page, call `draw(false)` instead of `draw()` but if you're adding new rows, there is little sense in preserving the current page

For example:

```js
var data = [['old',2,3,4,5,6]];

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'data': data
});

var dataNew = [['new',2,3,4,5,6]];
table.clear().rows.add(dataNew).draw();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/n2ahkmoz/) fro code and demonstration.